# why ApplicationContext not inherited from AbstractApplicationContext?

Tags: spring

I just noticed that in Spring, some methods like `registerShutdownHook` are only defined in `AbstractApplicationContext`, not in `ApplicationContext`.
I checked, ApplicationContext is not inherited from `AbstractApplicationContext`, I am wondering why?

Answer (score 0):

The `registerShudownHook` is defined on the  `AbstractApplicationContext` which is a template method implementation where you only define certain parts of functionalities (the rest is used as default).

`AbstractApplicationContext` is an implementation of the ApplicatoinContext, not the other way round, so the method you are referring to, cannot be acessed from field declared `ApplicationContext`.

This method actually comes from implementing the `ConfigurableApplicationContext` where it is originally defined.

**To illustrate:**

AbstractApplicatoinContext

```
  ^
  | implements 
  |
```

ConfigurableApplicationContext (this is where the method is defined)

```
  ^
  | extends
  |
```

AppliationContext